# How to figure out which network interface is used by NFS on Solaris 10?

Tags: solaris, nfs, network-interface

I have a server with 8 network interfaces configured. From it, I share some directories and export nfs mounts to other servers.

My question is how do I figure out which of the 8 interfaces is used by NFS? I want to disable one of them and I wouldn't want anything to happen to the mounts.

I am using Solaris 10.

Comment: can you see I/O counts for the interfaces and drive some big NFS traffic?

Comment: I was thinking of using snoop on each interface on ports 111 and 2049, however I am not sure how to generate significant traffic in order for it to show up on snoop. Also I don't think that I am allowed to unmount what is already mounted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from NFS server, try

```
netstat -an | grep 2049
```

you should see something like

```
      *.2049               *.*                0      0 49152      0 LISTEN
10.12.13.97.2049      10.12.13.90.914       49640      0 49640      0 ESTABLISHED
```

- first line saysthat  nfsd (service number  2049) is listening on all interfaces  `*.2049 LISTEN`
- next line says there is a connection from distant host `10.12.13.90`
- so connection goes on `10.12.13.X` network

you will connect with network using `netstat -in`

```
Name  Mtu  Net/Dest      Address        Ipkts  Ierrs Opkts  Oerrs Collis Queue
lo0   8232 127.0.0.0     127.0.0.1      711988047 0     711988047 0     0      0
aggr1 1500 10.12.13.0     10.12.13.97     102780417 0     171623103 0     0      0
aggr2 1500 10.22.33.0     10.22.33.97     2944376600 0     2272441510 0     0      0
```

hence nfs is using `aggr1`.

Comment: What if from `netstat -an` I obtain only `*.2049     Idle` and `*.2049              *.*                0      0 49152      0 LISTEN`?

Comment: @robertpas you have no actual connection

Comment: NFS can also use UDP.  But I don't have access to a running example of Solaris that uses serves NFS via UDP so I don't know how that would appear in `netstat` output,  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/584112/why-does-nfs-use-udp-by-default for more data on NFS over UDP.